# Show that $((p\Leftrightarrow q)\Leftrightarrow T)$ and $(p\Leftrightarrow (q\Leftrightarrow T))$ are logically equivalent using transformations

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I tried this but I'm not sure what to do about the T value:

$$((p\Leftrightarrow q ) \Leftrightarrow T ) \equiv \neg p \Leftrightarrow \neg q \Leftrightarrow T \equiv \neg p \Leftrightarrow \neg (\neg q \Leftrightarrow \neg T) \equiv \neg p \Leftrightarrow (q \Leftrightarrow T)$$

Am I using the rules correctly?

Comment: How about a truth table?

Comment: I already did the truth table for question A but B asks to do it with transformations

Comment: @memelord420xd what transformation rules do you have available?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $\quad r \equiv (r\leftrightarrow \top)$